# How to make a drop down list which can be filtered by another drop down list in cshtml

Tags: jquery, json, razor, filter, drop-down-menu

I wonder,for example,when I select "blocka" with value of BLOCK_CD[10000]  in the first drop down list, how can I make the second drop down list shows only OFFICE_NM[aaa] and [bbb] with value of [10000]

1.C#

```
@{
var dataCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlockCollection>(response1.JsonData);
}
```

2.json get from dataCollection above

```
{"Blocks":[
{"BLOCK_CD":"10000","BLOCK_NM":"blocka"},
{"BLOCK_CD":"20000","BLOCK_NM":"blockb"},],

"Offices":[
{"BLOCK_CD":"10000","OFFICE_CD":"001","OFFICE_NM":"aaa"},
{"BLOCK_CD":"10000","OFFICE_CD":"240","OFFICE_NM":"bbb"},
{"BLOCK_CD":"20000","OFFICE_CD":"243","OFFICE_NM":"ccc"},
{"BLOCK_CD":"20000","OFFICE_CD":"244","OFFICE_NM":"ddd"}]
```

3.drop down list made by json

```
<div>                        
<select name="bl" id="block">
@foreach (Block block in dataCollection.Blocks)
{
<option value=@block.BLOCK_CD>@block.BLOCK_NM</option>
}
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select name="of" id="office">
@foreach (Office office in dataCollection.Offices)
{
<option value=@office.OFFICE_CD>@office.OFFICE_NM</option>
}
</select>
</div>
```

I started to  learn programming a year ago, so maybe it's a simple question for you guys.And please help me,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like this:

```
$('#block').change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();

  $('#office option').hide().filter('[value="' + v + '"]').show().each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
      $(this).prop("selected", true);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This will only show those options in the second select that has the same value from the option you have selected in `#block`

**Demo**

```js
$('#block').change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();

  $('#office option').hide().filter('[value="' + v + '"]').show().each(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
      $(this).prop("selected", true);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="bl" id="block">

    <option value="10000">blocka</option>
    <option value="20000">blockb</option>

  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="of" id="office">

    <option value="10000">aaa</option>
    <option value="10000">bbb</option>
    <option value="20000">ccc</option>
    <option value="20000">ddd</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.But because I have to set value of second drop down list with OFFICE_CD but not the BLOCK_CD,so I think maybe I can't filter the second drop down list with BLOCK_CD?

Comment: Oh my god I made it! Thank you very much!!!! I set the tabindex of second drop down list with BLOCK_CD and exchange the "value" with "tabindex" in your source code and it worked!